# How to install Java 18 (JRE) on Ubuntu LTS 20.04

Tags: 20.04, minecraft, jre

My kid really wants me to upgrade the minecraft server I run from 1.17.1 to 1.18, but when I tried, I found that it required Java 18. It looks like Java 18 is only available on the latest release of Ubuntu, but I want to stick with the LTS releases. Is there a backport available for Java 18?

Comment: Oops. It needs Java 17, not Java 18. And, I learned from a similar question posted here that installing Java 17 is simply `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre`

Comment: Anyway, Java 18 would be released in March 2022. So you need to wait till March :)

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379110/problems-updating-java-on-ubuntu-20-04-for-minecraft-1-18)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Java Edition 1.17(21w19a), Minecraft requires Java 16 or newer. In Ubuntu 20.04 and later you can meet this requirement by installing openjdk-17-jre as follows:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre
```

Alternatively in Ubuntu 22.04 and later you can also meet this requirement by installing openjdk-18-jre with `sudo apt install openjdk-18-jre`